# Node JS: How to convert spaces to %20 in body-parser

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, body-parser

Is there a way for body-parser to automatically convert that? Because I have an android app that sends request to one of my urls but when there is a space in the text the request fails.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean your Android app is sending requests to a URL with spaces? URL's should have all spaces converted to `%20` before they are even sent to a server.